# #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: sql, row

When I wan't to connect two tables with eachother then I get the message : #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails....I want to connect oauth_uid2 (primary key) from the facebook_users tabel to the bugs tabel with the foreign key oauth_uid2. But I get always this message. I have already cleared my data but nothing works.Also in the table users_facebook I have 1 record.

> 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`phples`.`bugs`, CONSTRAINT `bugs_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`oauth_uid2`) REFERENCES `users_facebook` (`oauth_uid2`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

bugs table: FK = oauth_uid2, PK= bug_id

```
 #Name  Type    Collation   Attributes  Null    Default Extra   Action
     1  bug_id  int(30)         No  None    AUTO_INCREMENT    Change      Drop    Browse distinct values     Primary      Unique      Index  Spatial     Fulltext
     2  bugtitle    varchar(50) utf8_unicode_ci     No  None          Change      Drop    Browse distinct values      Primary     Unique      Index  Spatial     Fulltext
     3  bugdescription  varchar(500)    utf8_unicode_ci     No  None          Change      Drop    Browse distinct values      Primary     Unique      Index  Spatial     Fulltext
     4  oauth_uid2  int(30)         No  None          Change      Drop    Browse distinct values      Primary     Unique      Index  Spatial     Fulltext
```

users_facebook table: PK= oauth_uid2

```
#   Name    Type    Collation   Attributes  Null    Default Extra   Action
     1  oauth_uid2  int(30)         No  None          Change      Drop    Browse distinct values     Primary      Unique      Index  Spatial     Fulltext
     2  email   varchar(70) utf8_unicode_ci     No  None          Change      Drop    Browse distinct values      Primary     Unique      Index  Spatial     Fulltext
```

Comment: What query or admin action are you attempting to perform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've already got the tables linked, which is where the error is coming from. You need to make sure that you have a record in `users_facebook` **BEFORE** you try to insert a record into `bugs` with the same oauth_uid2, e.g.

```
users_facebook has records with oauth_uid2 `10`, `20`, `30`
```

you try to insert a record into `bugs` with

```
INSERT INTO bugs (oauth_uid2) VALUES (10) // works, there's a matching record in users_facebook
INSERT INTO bugs (oauth_uid2) VALUES (15) // fails, there's no user with that id.
```

Answer (score 2):

If you backup your Magento database using other tools, like phpMyAdmin or Navicat, these special statements will be missing. When you attempt to run the .sql file, you will get errors like these:

Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

This error occurs because the data you are importing is provided table by table, row by row, without regard to the logical structure and integrity of the database.

To restore a .sql file backup without constraint checking, simply add the following statements at the beginning of your .sql file:

```
SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT;
SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS;
SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION;
SET NAMES utf8;
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO';
SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0;
```

At the end of the file, add the statements required to turn on constraint checking again:

```
SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT;
SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS;
SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION;
SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES;
```

you will be able to do this.

Comment: Thanx. That saved my day!

After the import has stopped because of any sql error,
you get DUPLICATE ENTRY-errors on every INSERT-Statement that has been processed before.

That's why I replaced all the INSERT-Statements with REPLACE-Statements.

If there isn't something to replace, the REPLACE-Statement behaves like an INSERT-Statement.