# error trying to alter tables to add foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sql

I have built 2 tables.  forms and items.

```
| forms | CREATE TABLE `forms` (
`id` bigint(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`formName` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`dueDate` date DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=84 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci |
```

items:

```
| items | CREATE TABLE `items` (
`formId` bigint(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`id` bigint(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`itemName` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=56 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci |
```

forms is the parent, items is the child.

I am trying to alter the tables to add a foreign key, so that if forms.id gets deleted, the items in items with formId=forms.id gets deleted as well.

My question is i cant get anything i do to work, what am i doing wrong?

```
ALTER TABLE items ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (formId) REFERENCES forms(id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`server_newTeamSales`.`#sql-64e0_28020de`, CONSTRAINT `#sql-64e0_28020de_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`formId`) REFERENCES `forms` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)

ALTER TABLE forms ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES items(formId) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'server_newTeamSales.#sql-64e0_28020de' (errno: 150)
```

I am not even sure which table needs the keys, foreign keys are new to me, and i cant understand the mysql docs on the dev site.

Comment: Duplicated question. Please see: [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16594672/1452-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fails

Comment: Your first statement should work.  However it appears one or many forms has been deleted before the constraint was created.  You'll either need to add a form(s) back or delete the items which no longer relate to a form (orphans).  If you can just delete the items, then do this first then add the constraint `Delete from items where formID not in (Select ID from forms)`

Comment: i cleared out all forms data, as well as all items data. now which one to use, so when i delete a form, the associated items get deleted as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first issue there is probably an issue with data which is present in the table. There is probably a value in the child table that does not exist in the parent table.

Check like this:

```
SELECT formId FROM items WHERE formId NOT IN (SELECT id FROM forms)
```

For the second error you may probably try by making `formId` a primary key in `items` table.

Comment: I am trying to delete items when a form is deleted.  Should i use the first alter statement or the second?

Comment: @bart2puck:- You may try the first alter statement!